# Git: keep a subdirectory local-only

Tags: git

I have a project where I keep notes for my own use in `project/notes`, but the notes shouldn't be pushed to the remote repository.  That's easy enough to take of by adding the path to `project/.git/info/exclude`.  However, I'd like to use git to track changes to my notes.  Could I create a separate, local-only repository at `project/notes/.git` and store things there, or would that screw things up?  Should I put the `notes` directory outside the project and then make a symbolic link to it?  Or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there's no need to track changes in notes tied to the project version history, i.e. the notes folder is not expected to behave as if it was a submodule, you can just create a new repository under the ignored notes folder.

But if changes in notes have to be mapped to changes in the project without publishing the notes as a part of the project, then an alternative is to create an extra local only super project and add the real project as a submodule for that. Then you can have the notes either as the main content of that super project, or as another submodule, depending on just how you want to define the semantics of the project structure. In either case you don't have to specifically ignore your notes in the actual project. You would create a folder structure like this:

```
/your_local_super_project
----/project
--------/your_project_tree_here
----/notes
```

As you indicated that you can move your notes outside the project directory, this is likely what you should do. You get tracking for all the things you want to track and you can avoid interference between notes and the project. It's also more portable than fiddling with symbolic links.

Answer (score 2):

I have a quick fix but it's maybe not what you're expecting to do.

First create a .gitignore in your root project containing :

```
notes/
```

And then create a new git repository in your notes directory.